# what is the time complexity for "public boolean add(E e)" of Class PriorityQueue<E>?

Tags: java, performance

To be precise I am talking about : [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#add(E)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#add%28E%29)

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#add%28E%29

> Implementation note: this implementation provides O(log(n)) time for
>   the enqueing and dequeing methods (offer, poll, remove() and add);
>   linear time for the remove(Object) and contains(Object) methods; and
>   constant time for the retrieval methods (peek, element, and size).